# How to create a gRPC server in Python using proto3?

Tags: python-3.5, grpc, proto3

According to this http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html#creating-the-server and the examples here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.0.0/examples/python/route_guide, when I generate my `_pb2.py` file, several classes named `*Stub` and `*Servicer` should be created. However, my generated `_pb2.py` file doesn't contain anything like this.

This is how I generate my `_pb2.py` file:

```
protoc --proto_path=.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/tools/_proto/ --proto_path=.  --python_out=voyager/ voyager.proto
```

Is there something special about proto3 that means that these classes aren't generated? Or a `protoc` flag that I'm missing? I can't seem to figure out how to create a gRPC server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `--grpc_python_out=voyager/`. There are two plugins involved: Protobuf Python and gRPC Python. You are only running the Protobuf one.